# Bake test for subfolder controller with scaffolding

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm currently trying to bake a test controller with bin/cake test. The controller that I want to test (users controller) is in a subfolder with the following structure:

```
-- App
  -- src
    -- Controller
      -- Api
         - UsersController.php
         - AppController.php
```

When I try to do the following this will contain several bugs:

```
bin/cake bake test controller Api/users
```

Does anyone know what the proper way is to bake test controllers for a controller that is in a subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subfolders are namespaces, supply the controller name using the namespace separator, ie a backslash. Also use proper camel casing.

```
bin/cake bake test controller Api\Users
```